# Rails, order by number of matched tags and then by name

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, sql-order-by

Here's what I want to do: `Listing` has a many-to-many relationship with `Tag` through `Taggings`. I want to allow a user to search for listings by `title` (of the listing) and `name` (of zero or more tags). I want to order the number of results first by the listings with the greatest number of tags matched, and then by title.

It seems like this question has been done before -- it might be as simple as matching this question ([Ordering items with matching tags by number of tags that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783923/ordering-items-with-matching-tags-by-number-of-tags-that-match)) from MySQL. However, I'm not SQL-literate at all, which is why I'm asking for help.

**Update:**
Here is an example of what I want.

Say I have 3 listings.

`listing1` has tags "humor," "funny," and "hilarious."

`listing2` = 2 has tags "funny," "silly," and "goofy."

`listing3` = 3 has tags "funny," "silly," and "goofy."

`listing4` = 4 has the tag "completely serious."

If I make a search with the tags "funny" and "silly", what I should get back is listing2, listing3, listing1, and listing4 (ignoring titles for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I think you might have to use some SQL sugar to do this scope.

Something like this:

```
Listing
  .joins("LEFT JOIN taggings ON taggings.listing_id = listings.id")
  .joins('LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id AND tags.name IN ("funny","silly")')
  .group(:id)
  .order("count(tags.id), name DESC")
```

Does that help?

Comment: I seem to be having exceptions being thrown... perhaps it's something to do with the fact that I renamed listing_tags to taggings -- which is what my join table is called. I posted the code and error message above, but it's pretty cryptic to me what's happening.

Comment: Nevermind! It appears to have worked. Can you explain your answer (I have no idea what's going on)? Also, I tweaked the answer to make it work -- there was an issue with quotes and using `join` on `tag_names`

Comment: Sure!

First you need to left join on the `taggings` table. Left joining includes all rows from the first table, `listings`. This way you will still retrieve listings without taggings.

Comment: Then perform another left join on `tags` with the stipulation that they are the tags you are searching on, "funny" and "silly".

Comment: now if you group the joined query back up by listings you will be able to count up the ids of tags that matched for each listing, and order by it.

Comment: Just as a note: I had to change `order("count(tags.id), name DESC")` to `order("count(tags.id) DESC")` to order DESC on the tag count, and also `group(:id)` will have to be changed to `group("listings.id)` for PG users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a solution in pure ActiveRecord so as not to touch any SQL...

```
Listing.order("tags.count DESC, title")
```

In this case you'd probably be better off using a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) for tags to optimize your queries.

Comment: I think what you just gave me orders the listings by the number of tags they have -- not the matched tags. This isn't quite what I want -- see updated question.

Comment: This is far more complex than I expected. I've been trying on and off all day but I still haven't got it.